# HTML5 Wait until canvas loads then find base64

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Add wait until full canvas get loaded then find base64 of that canvas, instead of using time.

```
function make_base(bg_img, width, height)
{
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = bg_img;
  base_image.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, width, height);
  resolve()
  }
  })
}

function loadCanvas(width, height) {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.id = "canvas";
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
    setTimeout(function() {
    base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1);
    console.log(base64);
}, 3500);
}

function fillText(name, x_name, y_name, name_color, name_font) {
ctx.fillStyle = name_color;
ctx.font = name_font;
ctx.fillText(name, x_name, y_name);
}
```

Here Canvas some times takes time to load. As I have set 3.5 sec for base64 Url some times canvas content doesn't get loaded but I get blank base64.

```
function work() {
loadCanvas(x,y)
make_base(xxxxx).then(function () {
fillText(abcd)
})
}
```

How can I wait for base64 until full canvas is loaded.

Comment: A canvas doesn't load, and exept for its `toBlob` method, I think everything is synchronous (at least in the 2D API). You might be confusing with the HTMLImageElement, for which you indeed need to wait its load event before being able to use it e.g with `ctx.drawImage(img, x, y)`. But your code doesn't have such an image, so it is unclear what you are waiting for...

Comment: canvas does have bg. I have updated code.

Comment: Simply move your toDataURL out of that initializing function, and call it inside `make_base.then` callback instead? Why do you want it in `loadCanvas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the export part in an other function, that you'll call at the end of your Promise chain:

```js
var canvas, ctx;

work()
.then(function (url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}).catch(console.error);


function export_canvas() {
  base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
  console.log(base64);
  return base64;
}

function make_base(bg_img, width, height) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    base_image.src = bg_img;
    base_image.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, width, height);
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

function setupCanvas(width, height) {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.id = "canvas";
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
}

function fillText(name, x_name, y_name, name_color, name_font) {
  ctx.fillStyle = name_color;
  ctx.font = name_font;
  ctx.fillText(name, x_name, y_name);
}

function work() {
  setupCanvas(80, 40);
  return make_base("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png", 40, 40)
  .then(function () {
    fillText("abcd", 40, 10, "red");
    // ready to export
    return export_canvas();
  });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
```

Comment: That just solved my problem.  Can you help me with loading bar also.

Comment: function loading() {
    $("#load-screen").show().delay(3500).fadeOut();
}

Comment: that is my loading function I have set timeout in that also. Can I show that until whole canvas loads and create base64.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is going on but this *COULD* be a solution to your problem.

When you get the base64 string you're saying it's sometimes *blank*. Good. Put that string aside (in `BASE64_NOT_READY`) and use it to distinguish between *ready* and *not ready*, like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);

  if (base64 !== BASE64_NOT_READY)
  {
    // ready, break interval and proceed
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log(base64);
  }
}, 100); // check every 100 ms, actual time depends on way too many factors
```

What you need is to determine the string:

```
var BASE64_NOT_READY = "???";
```

You can determine it by using your own code. Replace the `???` and you should be golden!